# Javascript sort by order of other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a large dataset I need to sort by a preset order.  It's simple enough to get the array sorted, but the problem is having the values not in the sort order moving to the *bottom* instead of the top.  Here's my code...

```
var order = ["value1",  "value2", "value3"];
var result = ["value4", "value2","value1","value1", "value3"].sort(function(a,b) {
    var aIndex = order.indexOf(a),
        bIndex = order.indexOf(b);

    if (aIndex > bIndex)
        return 1;
    if (aIndex < bIndex)
        return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

...and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtfsven/a3LfP/).

I can't figure out how to have a condition that considers something not in the order array to be a lower sort order.  I've tried adding `if (aIndex < 0 || bIndex < 0) return -1;` before the existing conditions, but this will be potentially incorrect of one of the two *is* in the sort order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting `aIndex` and `bIndex` to the length of the `order` array when they are -1, thus pushing them to the end of the array.

Example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3LfP/1/